# Jetpack Compose: force recomposition when a state changes from another activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have two Activities: `ActivityOne.kt` and `ActivityTwo.kt`. Both of them use Jetpack Compose to display an UI. In the first one, an item (let's say, a `Text`) has to be shown with variable `showtText` is `true`, and hidden when it's false. I achieve this by using:

```
@Composable
fun MyUI(){   
 AnimatedVisibility(visible = viewModel.showText) {
      Text("Some text")      
   }
}
```

My variable `showText` is defined in a ViewModel such as:

```
val showText by mutableStateOf(false)
```

That way, anytime I change the value of `showText` within my ViewModel when `ActivityOne.kt` is visible, it appears or disaappears. What I want to achieve is the following:

1. From `ActivityOne.kt` the user can navigate to `ActivityTwo.kt` (with the first one running in background, it's not cleared from the stack).
2. There, there's a `Switch` that can toggle `showText` value.
3. When the user press "back", `ActivityTwo.kt` calls `finish()` and it dissapears, showing again `ActivityOne.kt` (it was in the stack).
4. If user has toggled `showText` value in `ActivityTwo.kt`, the text should be hidden or shown automatically, as the state of `showText` has changed.

The problem is that, although the value of `showText` does change, the UI in `ActivityOne.kt` does not respond to those changes. I've checked that recomposition of `ActivityOne.kt`'s UI is not taking place after `ActivityTwo.kt` is finished, because it is not remembering the previous state of `showText`.

How could I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**
The problem is a little more difficult as I explained, but the basis are the same. Here is my complete code:

*ActivityOne.kt:*

```
class ActivityOne : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var vm: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val vmFactory = MainViewModelFactory()
        vm = ViewModelProvider(this, vmFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface {
                    MyUI()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyUI() {
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = myPrefs.showText) {
            Text("Some text")
        }
    }
}
```

*MainViewModel.kt:*

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        val myPrefs by mutableStateOf( AppPrefs() )
    }
}
```

*ActivityTwo.kt:*

```
class ActivityTwo : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface {
                    MyUI2()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyUI2() {
        val showText = remember {
            mutableStateOf(MainViewModel.myPrefs.showText)
        }

        Switch(
            checked = showText.value,
            onCheckedChange = {
                showText.value = it
                MainViewModel.myPrefs.showText = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

*AppPrefs.kt:*

```
class AppPrefs {
    var showText: Boolean = false
}
```

Comment: The recomposition is not taking place because the value did not change. You are seeing this behavior because you get a different instance of your `ViewModel` in each of the Activities. Changing the `showText` value in the VM from `ActivityTwo` does not change the `showText` value in the VM from `ActivityOne`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Ma3x ! In fact I'm not creating a new instance of the ViewModel, my property showText is inside a companion object in the only instance of the ViewModel (created by ActivityOne), and I access it within ActivityTwo.

Comment: Post both the ViewModel code and the code that is changing the value in ActivityTwo, because with a single ViewModel instance the value updates for me as expected, even though ActivityOne is on the backstack and paused.

Comment: Thanks again, @Ma3x ! I've uptaded the question and posted the code. Hopefully now it's clearer what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recomposition is not taking place because `mutableStateOf` is tracking the state of `myPrefs` which is never changed (the reference itself never changes).

You can achieve the recomposition in a few ways.

Here I will be assuming that your `AppPrefs` class either already contains more than one member/field, or that you would want to add more members to it in the future easily. That is why I added 2 more properties to it in the samples below and I only suggested solutions where adding more members won't affect the existing code.

## Option 1

If you can change the `AppPrefs` class to track the state of each property individually, then make these changes

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        val myPrefs = AppPrefs()
    }
}

class AppPrefs {
    var showText by mutableStateOf(false)
    var prop2 by mutableStateOf(0)
    var prop3: String? by mutableStateOf(null)
}
```

Everything else stays the same. Here the recomposition works again because now the state is tracked on members that are actually being changed.

## Option 2

If you can't (or don't want to) have `mutableStateOf` inside `AppPrefs` you can change `AppPrefs` from a normal `class` to a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html). In that way you get the `copy` function automatically implemented (alongside `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` and `componentN` for destructuring support).

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        // the only change here is val -> var
        var myPrefs by mutableStateOf(AppPrefs())
    }
}

// data class instead of a normal class
data class AppPrefs(
    val showText: Boolean = false,
    val prop2: Int = 0,
    val prop3: String? = null,
)
```

In this case you have to also change how you change the value of `myPrefs`. This is what makes the recomposition work correctly again

```kotlin
    onCheckedChange = {
        showText.value = it
        MainViewModel.myPrefs = MainViewModel.myPrefs.copy(showText = it)
    }
```

In case you cannot use a data class, then you can still go with option 2, but you implement the `copy` function on your existing class

```kotlin
// normal class with a copy function
class AppPrefs(
    val showText: Boolean = false,
    val prop2: Int = 0,
    val prop3: String? = null,
) {
    fun copy(
        showText: Boolean = this.showText,
        prop2: Int = this.prop2,
        prop3: String? = this.prop3,
    ) = AppPrefs(showText, prop2, prop3)
}
```

---

As a bonus, if you go with any of the above solutions, you can even simplify your existing code for the `MyUI2` composable and the recomposition will still work.

Example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyUI2() {
    val showText = MainViewModel.myPrefs.showText

    Switch(
        checked = showText,
        onCheckedChange = {
            // for Option 1
            MainViewModel.myPrefs.showText = it
            // for Option 2
            MainViewModel.myPrefs = MainViewModel.myPrefs.copy(showText = it)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I used option 2 with a regular class, as I didn't want to use a data class for AppPrefs, and it worked perfectly fine! Thank you for your help!